# How to call a javascript in HttpClient or Html Unit 

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, httpclient, htmlunit

I am using http client POST method to perform specific action in a website ,
for that it uses javascript of ajax connection which produces a requestID 
i.e `var reqID = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000001);`  to post .
I want to access that reqID to make the action performed .
can anyone help me regarding how to access a java script in HttpClient ?
Or can we access the specific reqID variable of javascript using HtmlUnit ?

My JS includes:

```
ajaxConnection.prototype.execute = function() {
    var reqID = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000001);
    var params = "reqID=" + reqID ;
    for (var key in this.connection_parameters) {
        params += "&" + key + "=" + this.connection_parameters[key];
    }
```

and i am calling POST to get the action performed i.e

```
String Src = PageSource_Post("http://www.example.com/ajax/ratingClient.php", new String[][]{{"reqID",""},{"id", "329602"},{"cmd", "rate"},{"rating", "2"},}, null);
```

as of now i have kept the reqID blank and other parameters are getting from pagesource !

I am trying with HtmlUnit also like

```
webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
HtmlPage firstPage = webClient.getPage("http://www.example.com/");
HTMLScriptElement script = new HTMLScriptElement();
```

From here do i have to access the particular `reqID` variable?

Comment: post your code so the community can help you better

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza my js includes `ajaxConnection.prototype.execute = function(){
 var reqID = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000001);
 var params = "reqID=" + reqID ;
 for( var key in this.connection_parameters ){
  params += "&" + key + "=" + this.connection_parameters[key];}`                   and i am calling POST to get the action performed i.e
`String Src = PageSource_Post("http://www.example.com/ajax/ratingClient.php", new String[][]{{"reqID",""},{"id", "329602"},{"cmd", "rate"},{"rating", "2"},}, null);`

as of now i have kept the reqID blank and other parameters are getting from pagesource !!

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza i am trying with HtmlUnit also like 

`webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 HtmlPage firstPage = webClient.getPage("http://www.example.com/");
 HTMLScriptElement script = new HTMLScriptElement();
`
from here do i have to access the particular `var reqID = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000001);` or the total js to get the exact value

Comment: @Aspirant: You should EDIT your post to include your code (NOT add the code as a comment). It's more readable and that's what editing is for. :)

Comment: This is a php question, not a Java question (http://www.example.com/ajax/ratingClient.php), or you want help to achieve this in Java?

Comment: Hey @LuiggiMendoza !! this is a java question , the only thing is that the website i am accessing is of .php !! anyway the question is while posting the request it gives reqID as request values which i got through LiveHttpHeaders , but the thing is the reqID which makes the request process is in javascript !! Can you help me regarding how to call javascript in HtmlUnit ....

Answer (score 0):

you mean web browser?

firebug for firefox and <kbd>F12</kbd> for IE

These tools will help you to debug javascript, you should toggle a break point in your javascript codes, and run step by step to see the value of your reqID

Comment: I assume when he said [HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) or [HTML Unit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/), then he meant "HTTPClient or HTML Unit" and not "a web browser".

Comment: @yahz bro i am using HttpClient , so i have done the debugging process using firebug and found the reqID is firing from ajaxconnection.js from my pagesource !!
now since i need the reqID to be POSTED which is in javascript i need guidance regarding how to access that reqID variable from javascript using HttpClient or Html UNIT .....

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to execute javascript from within Java. Personally, I've found HTMLUnit, and HTTPUnit's javascript support a bit lacking. We have had similar issues, and had great success using Selenium. You can create a quick test case using the Selenium IDE which is a firefox plugin(http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) . It allows you to record your steps from within Firefox, and export the test case to a JUnit test. Here is a good link for the steps.  http://university.utest.com/selenium-basics-part-3-record-test-case-and-export-in-junit-format/